# Powershell automatic variables

Tags: variables, powershell

So I got this code :

```
$t1, $t2, $t3, $t4, $t5, $t6, $t7, $t8, $t9, $t10, $t11 = $list[0].split(" ")
```

but is too much, and I think I can automate the creation of `$t` variables.
How is the correct procedure? with loop but to have the same result.

```
for ($i=0;$i -le 21; $i++) {
    $objResult += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{"C$i" = ($list[0].split(" "))[$i]} 
}
```

or with

```
set-variable -name "T$i" -value ($list[0].split(" "))[$i]
```

Comment: Honestly? Use an array here. If your variable names are really `$t1`, `$t2`, etc. there is nothing interesting being learned from the names (as opposed to `$id`, `$name`, etc.) and you could just as well use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are simple variables, `Set-Variable` works perfectly. like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {
set-variable -name "test$i" -value $i
}

$test0
$test1
$test2

PS > .\test.ps1
0
1
2
```

If you are looking to work with somewhat more complicated variables (such as COM objects for instance) then `New-Object` is what you need.

Comment: yes I wil prefer object but:

`for ($i = 0; $i -lt 22; $i++) {
    $objResult += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        "test$i" = ($list[0].split(" "))[$i]
    }
}`

I got: only the last property:test22, it doesn't save them all.

`TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
.....            
test0       NoteProperty System.String test0=1384630490`